# Call of overloaded template function is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Type> inline Type max(Type t1, Type t2) { 
    return t1 > t2 ? t1 : t2; 
}

template <typename Type> inline Type max(const std::vector<Type> &vec) { 
    return *std::max_element(vec.begin(),vec.end());
} 

template <typename Type> inline Type max(const Type *parray, int size) {
return *std::max_element(parray,parray+size);
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string sarray[] = {"we","were","her","pride","of","ten"};
    std::vector<std::string> svec(sarray,sarray+6);

    int iarray[] = {12,70,2,169,1,5,29};
    std::vector<int> ivec(iarray,iarray+7);

    float farray[] = {2.5,24.8,18.7,4.1,23.9};
    std::vector<float> fvec(farray,farray+5);

    int imax = max(max(ivec),max(iarray,7));
    float fmax = max(max(fvec),max(farray,5));
    std::string smax = max(max(svec),max(sarray,6));

    std::cout << "imax should be 169  -- found: " << imax << '\n'
              << "fmax should be 24.8 -- found: " << fmax << '\n'
              << "smax should be were -- found: " << smax << '\n';
    return 0; 
}
```

I am attempting to implement two simple template functions to output the max element of a vector and an array. However, I am receiving the following error when the type is a string.

```
error: call of overloaded 'max(std::string, std::string)' is ambiguous
```

Why is this occuring, and what is the best way to remedy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
std::string smax = max(max(svec),max(sarray,6));
```

translates to:

```
std::string smax = max(string ,string );
```

After `max(svec)` and `max(sarray,6)` are evaluated using your templates. Now here the problem arises:
The standard library already comes with a templated max() function. The compiler will be unable to tell whether you want your version of `max()` or `std::max()`.
Now you will ask why it worked for integers and floats. Answer is in this line you are specifically mentioning `std::string`. Hence the compiler is getting confused. 
There can be work arounds. But since you need the best solution, I would say rename your max function say MAximum.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the compiler is finding multiple matching definitions of `max` via [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) and it doesn't know which to choose.

Try changing the call to `max` to use its qualified-id:

```
std::string smax = ::max(max(svec),max(sarray,6));
```

Comment: @idealistikz that's because you have a typo, just remove the extra semicolon on that line.

Comment: How would I get it to work with my defined function `max` since it works with the other types?

Comment: it works with the other types because they don't live in the `std` namespace like `std::string` does. either name your function differently (e.g. `my_max`) or use its qualified-id like i've shown.

Answer (score 0):

**Why is this occuring?**
The compiler error already tells you why. It does not know which version of `max` to use.

> note: candidates are:
>   main.cpp:6:38: note: Type max(Type, Type) [with Type = std::basic_string]
>   ...
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:210:5: note: const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string]

**Solution:**
either explicitely call your `max` function or just call `std::max` (which already exists, so why would you want to reimplement it?).

Additionally, there is one `;` too much after `<< "fmax should be 24.8 -- found: " << fmax << '\n'`

Comment: I want to reimplement it because I'm attempting to understand template functions.